# Problema com ValueObject no Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ddd

Estou tendo uma dificuldade com um mapeamento e gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso:

Possuo uma classe de Contato com dois campos que são ValueObject do tipo "Telefone", os campos são Telefone e Celular.

```
public Telefone Telefone { get; set; }
public Telefone Celular { get; set; }
```

Gostaria de fazer o seguinte mapeamento, de forma que Telefone seja obrigatório e o celular não:

```
Property(x => x.Telefone.DDD)
  .HasColumnName("TelefoneDDD")
  .IsRequired();
Property(x => x.Telefone.Numero)
  .HasColumnName("Telefone")
  .IsRequired();
Property(x => x.Celular.DDD)
  .HasColumnName("CelularDDD")
  .IsOptional();
Property(x => x.Celular.Numero)
  .HasColumnName("Celular")
  .IsOptional();
```

Quando mando gerar o migration, me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Conflicting configuration settings were specified for property 'Numero' on type 'SistemaTeste.Domain.ValueObject.Telefone': 
>   IsNullable = False conflicts with IsNullable = True

Comment: Obs.: Se eu colocar todos como IsOptional ou IsRequired eles funcionam.

Comment: Você poderia colocar na sua pergunta a definição do objeto complexo `Telefone`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deveria ter uma configuração separada para a entidade Telefone e apenas fazer a chave para os dois campos na sua entidade principal. Em um deles vc deixa como Obrigatório e o outro não

```
public class Telefone
{
    public int Codigo {get;set;}
    public int DDD {get;set;}
    public string Numero {get;set;}
}

public class Cadastro
{
    public int CodigoTelefone {get;set;}
    public Telefone Telefone {get;set;}
    public int? CodigoCelular {get;set;}
    public Telefone Celular {get;set;}
}

//Mapeamento da classe Cadastro

HasRequired(c => c.Telefone)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.CodigoTelefone)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); // Telefone é obrigatório

HasOptional(c => c.Celular)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.CodigoCelular)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); // Celular não é obrigatório
```

Comment: Entendi como fazer dessa maneira, mas eu não gostaria de gerar mais uma tabela no banco, gostaria de gerar esses campos na minha tabela de contato. Usar ele como ValueObject. Uma outra opção seria joga-los diretamente na minha classe contato e fazer as validações, mas fugiria do conceito que gostaria de usar.

Comment: Se vc criar a classe Celular herdando de Telefone talvez dê certo. Não sei te afirmar. Ambas seriam uma classe Telefone e você poderia fazer o mapeamento desse jeito que já está feito hoje (suspeito). faça o teste e conte pra gente ^^

Comment: Funciona, embora não fique ainda do jeito que esperava é um alternativa. Eu fico imaginando se por algum motivo eu criar um ValueObject mais complexo e precisar usá-lo com mapeamentos diferentes para outras classes, sempre terei que criar classes herdadas para contornar isso. Ex.: Um CPF pode ser obrigatório para uma tabela de cliente e opcional em uma tabela X, se eu trabalhar com tipo primitivo apenas validando está ok, mas se eu quiser criar uma classe para encapsular o CPF esbarrarei nesse problema novamente.

Answer (score 0):

A solução para este problema realmente não é elegante. De acordo com [essa pergunta](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/35) aberta no Github do Entity Framework há uma limitação em como ele mapeia as entidades em seu modelo conceitual (C-Space).

*Obs.: A resposta no Github é posterior a essa questão e por isso achei interessante postar aqui.*

A solução que tenho usado é muito parecida com a que o gabriel.santos sugeriu: criar value objects (VO) que são subclasses de outros VO e configurar apenas as subclasses de acordo com a necessidade de cada entidade. Ex.:

```
// classes
public class Telefone { /*...* /} 
public class TelefoneFixo : Telefone { /**/ }
public class TelefoneCelular : Telefone  { /**/ }

// propriedades de Contato
public TelefoneFixo Telefone { get; set; }
public TelefoneCelular Celular { get; set; }

// a configuração da entidade permanece inalterada
```

**[Adendo]**
Existem outros problemas contornáveis referentes ao mapeamento de entidades que usam tipos complexos como VO: não é possível o uso de propriedades de um tipo complexo em chaves primárias, na composição de relacionamentos (FK) ou ainda como parâmetro para o método AddOrUpdate.